# Prepositional phrase

Tags: grammar

> I  found **Berhman in his room** helpless with pain and fever.

I have read about the following structure associated with the word "find":

- *"find (object) (adjective)"*.

But I am somehow confused with this sentence, choosing between

1. **"Berhman in his room"** as the object of **"found"**, and
2. **"in his room"** as the adverb of **"found"**.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have read find object adjective?" The prepositional phrase "in his room" does not serve as an adverbial phrase. Instead, it modifies "Berhman," which is the object of "found."

Comment: It looks as if you put punctuation in random places here and there without rhyme or reason. We use a space only **after** punctuation, not **before** it. What does "helpless with help" mean?

Comment: "Berhman" is direct object of "found". The object complement is the AdjP "helpless with pain and fever". The preposition phrase "in his room" is a locative complement of "found".

Answer (score 2):

Functions of each constituents is shown below -

> [I]**<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub>** [found]**<sub>[PREDICATOR]</sub>** [Berhman]**<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub>** [in his room]**<sub>ADJUNCT</sub>** [helpless with help]**<sub>COMPLEMENT</sub>**.

**I** -> COMPLEMENT (Subject) -> Realized by a pronoun, a subclass of Noun Phrase.

**found** -> PREDICATOR -> Realized by a verb.

**Berhman** -> COMPLEMENT (Object) -> Realized by a Noun Phrase.

**in his room** -> ADJUNCT -> Realized by a Prepositional Phrase.

**helpless with help** -> COMPLEMENT -> Realized by Adjective Phrase.

Comment: Would you not consider that "in his room" is a locative complement rather than an adjunct? The PP is structurally comparable with a predicative (it is object orientated) and hence comparable to assigning a property to the object "Berhman".

Comment: @BillJ that is what I initially thought. But then it occurred to me that we can drop that PP without making that sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: That's true, but then omissibility is not always a good test for adjuncthood. In general, complements can often be dropped without loss of grammaticality but they are still complements, as in "We cycled [from Oxford to Banbury]"; "I left my wallet at home, so Jill paid [the bill]". If we compare examples like "The keys are [in the drawer]" and "I hid the keys [in the drawer]", the PP "in the drawer" has a similar function in both since it denotes the location of the keys. And yet the PP is a complement in the first, and an adjunct in the second. Interesting!

Comment: @BillJ I think I have a reason to not consider that PP as a complement. The verb - *find* - licences two slots. Both are complement -  one is object and the other is predicative complement. If that AdjP is a predicative complement, the PP has to be an adjunct. On the other hand, in the absence of that AdjP, that PP is a complement.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about "find" having 2 complements, the object "Berhman" and the PC "helpless with pain and fever". The bit about the PP "in his room" is subtle, perhaps, and it certainly looks like a locative adjunct, but I'm reasonably certain that it is a 3rd complement of "find". Have you got a copy of CGEL to hand?

Comment: @BillJ no. But if you can give me page no. I can check later

Comment: It's discussed on p257. An example quoted is "I kept it in the drawer" where the PP "in the drawer" is given as a locative complement. That would equate with "I found Berhman in his room".

Comment: @BillJ yes in that example the verb *keep* has that two slots. And that's why that PP is a complement. But I really doubt about the existence of third complement slot of *find*

Comment: If you then extend that example to "I kept it clean in the drawer", then there would be 3 complements: the object, the PC, and the locative complement.

Comment: @BillJ hmmm but is that sentence really correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Other similar examples might be: "I kept it safe in the attic"; "They left me tired in the waiting room". There's no doubt (per CGEL) that the PPs are locative complements, and those examples have objects and PCs too, so I can't see a flaw in the analysis.

Comment: @BillJ hmmm these are better sentences. But whether complement or not, I'm not sure. I have to read more about these things. Btw thanks for a nice chat :-) see you.

Comment: Okay, but do take a look at p257; I think you'll be convinced! I think the crucial point is that the locatives in those examples are object orientated, just like in the OP's.

Comment: @BillJ thanks. I will for sure, but later.

Answer (score -1):

I use traditional, standard English grammar, and this might help...

> I found Berhman in his room helpless with pain and fever.

This is a Simple Sentence with one subject "I" and one verb "found."

"found" is a transitive verb and takes an object, here, a direct object: Berhman.

The verb "found" is modified by an adverb prepositional phrase "in his room" to answer what an adverb would ask, "*Where*?" Where did you find Berhman? In his room.

The preposition phrase consists of the preposition "in" a possessive pronoun "his" and the object of the preposition (a noun or pronoun) "room."

An adjective doesn't always have to come right next to the word it modifies, so "helpless" is just that an adjective modifying "Berhman."

e.g. I found *helpless* Berhman in his room with pain and fever. [sounds awkward, hence, it's placed later in the sentence]

The adjective "helpless" simply means "without help or defense" and is being modified to by the adverb prepositional phrase "with pain and fever." The phrase answers, "To what extent?" To what extent was he helpless? Pain and fever caused him to become helpless more or less.

The objects for the preposition "without" are "help, defense" [both nouns]

So...

> But I am somehow confused with this sentence, choosing between
>
> "Berhman in his room" as the object of "found", and
>
> "in his room" as the adverb of "found".

You are correct on both.

Again, *Berhman* is the object (direct object) of *found*.

*in his room* is the adverb modifying *found.*

Comment: No, "helpless with pain and fever" is not a modifier; it is an objective predicative complement of "found". The preposition phrase "in his room" is locative complement of "found".

Comment: @BillJ it's true that AdjP is a predicative complement. But it is at the same time a modifier of the object.

Comment: I never said "helpless with pain and fever" is a modifier. The definition of "helpless" as an adjective: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helpless // is separately modifying the direct object, and the adverb phrase "with pain and fever" is modifying the adjective. Please review the Eight Parts of Speech for what an adjective and an adverb functions as; also, learn about prepositional phrases: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/preposition_definition.htm and http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/prepositional_phrase.htm //

Comment: You said "helpless" was a modifier, and since "with pain and fever" is part of the adjective phrase, it follows that you are saying "helpless with pain and fever" is a modifier, which it isn't.

Comment: The adjective "helpless" simply means "without help or defense" and is being modified to by the adverb prepositional phrase "with pain and fever." I never said "adjective phrase." You don't know what an "adverb prepositional phrase" is? Learn about it. You use linguistic grammar, mine is based on textbooks like this: http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/HooverCity/SpainParkHigh/Uploads/Forms/Start%20Holt%20Handbook%2010.pdf

Comment: I'm aware of what "helpless" means"! The adjective phrase is "helpless with pain and fever" in which "helpless" is head and the PP with pain and fever" is complement. The AdjP is undisputedly objective predicative complement. I'm sorry, but you've analysed most of the OP's example incorrectly.

Comment: Can I ask you, "Whether the way I have it, traditionally, or your definition of  adjective + adverb prep. phr. = adjective phrase, does mine and yours function as a modifier and do they both modify Berhman? Yes or No? // BTW, here's my book: John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Third Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. This is my understanding of traditional, everyday grammar.

Comment: No, the AdjP "helpless with pain and fever" is not modifying "Berhman"; it is an objective predicative complement of "find". It is of course object orientated, hence its name "objective PC" but there is a big difference between modifiers and complements. A typical and very commonly-used example is "They painted the house red", where "house" is direct object and "red" is objective PC (not modifier).